# Multiple separate plots in one go

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot2:

```
qplot(carat, price, data = diamonds) + facet_grid(cut ~ color ~ clarity)
```

Not quite what I hoped.  How could something like this be done, except producing separate grids of plots per level of clarity, e.g.

```
qplot(carat, price, data = diamonds[diamonds$clarity=="SI2", ]) + facet_grid(cut ~ color)
qplot(carat, price, data = diamonds[diamonds$clarity=="VS1", ]) + facet_grid(cut ~ color)
```

and so on.

Something using cast would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
base = qplot(carat, price, data = diamonds) + facet_grid(cut ~ color)
lp = dlply(diamonds, "clarity", `%+%`, e1 = base)

library(gridExtra)
do.call(grid.arrange, lp) # all in one page

# or multiple pages (with layout passed to grid.arrange)
all = do.call(marrangeGrob, c(lp, ncol=2, nrow=1))
ggsave("multipage.pdf", all, width=12)
```

Answer (score 2):

For three facetting variables, try `facet_wrap` instead.

```
facet_wrap(~ cut + color + clarity)
```

---

I've reread the question.  If you actually want multiple plots (it wasn't that clear from the phrasing), then just loop over the levels of `clarity`.

```
for(clarity in levels(diamonds$clarity))
{
  p <- qplot(carat, price, data = diamonds[diamonds$clarity == clarity, ]) + 
    facet_grid(cut ~ color)
  print(p)
}
```

Or, if you are `for`-loop-phobic,

```
l_ply(
  levels(diamonds$clarity),
  function(clarity)
  {
    qplot(carat, price, data = diamonds[diamonds$clarity == clarity, ]) + 
      facet_grid(cut ~ color)
  }
)
```

If you are printing to the screen, turn on history recording first.  Otherwise include a call to `ggsave` in your loop.

Comment: This produces the same plots as my attempt, only arranged less usefully.

Comment: Both perfect answers, but had to pick one.