# output ggplot results in one pdf but several pages in R

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I have at least 10 plots by ggplot(we can call them plot1, plot2 ....). I can output them into separate pdf files. But I prefer to output them in only one pdf file but several pages. One page, one plot from ggplot.

I tried to list all plots and use ggsave but it can not work. Any idea or script can help? Thank you

Comment: [here's one option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16733354/471093)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See the `pdf` function for this.

For three plots it would look like this (saving into your working directory with default naming).  Run through `dev.off` line before you can open file.

```
pdf()
plot1
plot2
plot3
dev.off()
```

If your plots are already stored in a list named `list1`:

```
pdf()
list1
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried both. This first one can work. The second one can not.

Comment: @cutebunny I actually use the second version much more often than the first when I have lots of plots I want to make and peruse.  See, e.g., [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19147917/2461552).

Answer (score 6):

Based on aosmith's answer, here's a simple wrapper function to save lists of ggplot2 plots to a single pdf.

```
GG_save_pdf = function(list, filename) {
  #start pdf
  pdf(filename)

  #loop
  for (p in list) {
    print(p)
  }

  #end pdf
  dev.off()

  invisible(NULL)
}
```